# GetForegroundWindow always returns 0 for Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-services

I write simple Windows service and trying to get `hwnd` of active window:

```
private int _hwnd;

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

`_hwnd` always equals 0 here. Why? Is there any way to get the correct (`!= 0`) value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vista and 7, services cannot interact with the desktop. See [Interactive Services on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28VS.85%29.aspx).